# Style identification: How was this effect created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, style-identification, corel-draw

Does anyone know how this effect was created? I remember seeing someone do this on Photoshop a few years ago but I can't remember what tools he used/what filters he used.
If anyone knows what's it called it would make my day!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What effect are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop CC 2015.1 brought back an ever more powerful [Oil Filter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/oil-paint-filter.html) which is what creates this effect.

Comment: Sure it's not the drop shadow that is asked about? The question mentions "a couple of years ago" and I cannot recall "Oil filter" from around that time (or *ever*).

Comment: Am I sure? No. He could be talking about the color red for all I know. But the most complex effect on the image is the Oil Filter which has existed since 2012 (4 years). @RadLexus